# Filter unsorted list using url #value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm hacking my way through creating a portfolio website and have come a little unstuck with the Javascript /Jquery filtering of the portfolio elements. As i'm new to it, I'm keeping things as simple as possible with a very basic filter which shows / hides elements in an unsorted list "portfolio" using another  to act as a filter "filter" when it's clicked upon.

On the page itself, things are working ok, the links are filtering as they should but I want to add a link elsewhere on the site back to the portfolio page which will filter the portfolio accordingly using the #value. For example I'd want the link to 'portfolio.html#things' to apply the filter of 'things' to my list. After googling/  trawling round these parts, i've come unstuck and been found out.

Can anyone help out a total noob?  I've created a JSFiddle with the js and html that i'm using at the moment here: http://jsfiddle.net/2x7xme5u/6/

And this is the js which i'm using at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul#filter a').click(function () {
$(this).css('outline', 'none');
$('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
$(this).parent().addClass('current');

var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

if (filterVal == 'all') {
    $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
} else {

    $('ul#portfolio li').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow').addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    });
}

return false;
```

Apologies if i'm missing some blatantly obvious information!

Gah! - now with public Fiddle. (Sorry)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the anchor tag using

```
var url = window.location.href;
var anchor = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));
var tag = anchor.substring(1);

if (tag) {
    if (tag == 'all') {
        $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').show();
    } else {

        $('ul#portfolio li').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass(tag)) {
                $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/bs45px6f/7/

Comment: Thanks @Russell-Bevan This is a really helpful start. So given that with this I can now define the anchor variable and assign it a value, how would i create an if loop that checks whether the value of 'anchor' = one of my filters? Apologies, i'm really new to this and pretty feckless.

Comment: No worries, give me a few and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Genuinely really appreciated! Will try implement this from home tonight. With this, do i then effectively replace the 'url' value on the first line of your fiddle with: window.location.href as outlined above?

Comment: Yes window.location.href will return the full url with the anchor attached.

Comment: Thanks so much for this @russell-bevan just to be a pest, one last question, is there away to set this so that if there is no # present in the URL that it defaults to show all? Currently it shows none.

Comment: @EuanMackay updated jsFiddle link with new solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @russell-bevan you can't imagine how much hassle that has saved me. So much appreciated!